# How to make an Android quiz app?

Tags: android, eclipse

My friend and I are new to programming and we decided to make a series of android apps for our psychology class. We have downloaded Eclipse, the SDK file for Android 2.3.3, etc. but we still have close to no idea on what to do. We have searched youtube and google and yet we have found no answers to our question. What is the format and coding for a simple quiz app? We are planning to put this on the Android Market, so please don't refer us to the google app inventor. Thank you! :)

Comment: Is your purpose really to make a quiz for your psychology class? Or to learn android programming? Because you could easily make a quiz for your psychology class through other existing applications/frameworks, without any programming at all. And the bonus is that some of those solutions are cross-platforms. So you wouldn't have to exclude all the iPhone users from taking your quiz.

Answer (score 4):

Question 1:  Do you know Java?   I ask beacuse android apps are written in it.

Question 2:  Do you know XML?   Android apps are formatted in this (especially for basic apps like a quiz one)

I found that the best thing to do is pick up an easy book.  Beginning Android Development by Wei-Meng Lee, or I think there is a Head First: Android Dev. book out there that will help you learn from scratch very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

Find an online quiz hosting site. Generate your quiz(zes) and copy down the full URL link.
Create a [webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) using the link.  If you plan to have multiple, then look at the other android dev tutorials on buttons and such.

Answer (score 0):

Spend a day learning from the basics of Android, start from HelloWorld of Android. You will find a good and nice tutorial to help you out on the official android site...

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the place you got the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from, and check out the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html), [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), and [Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) tabs to get a good grounding in how to create your first app.

When you've written a few basic apps, go find a book that will help - I personally recommend the books by Mark Murphy ([CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is the android development web site 
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html and just read some example to see how the project is organized. And try the simple "Hello world" program to see how to run the app through in the virtual machine or a real device.